# How can you find the DOI of an article that doesn't seem to have one?

Tags: publications, doi

I cannot find the DOI number of [this article](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/234793205_Experimental_analysis_of_pattern_similarity_between_Bessel_kernel_and_born-Jordan_kernel). It has ISBN, but it does not help me find its DOI number.

**How can you find the DOI number of articles where it's not listed, but other identifiers, such as an ISBN, are available?**

Comment: What leads you to think that it's got a DOI?

Comment: There is a [conversion agreement](http://www.doi.org/factsheets/ISBN-A.html) between DOI and ISBN. For the actual converted DOI, perhaps you can contact the ISBN organization (contact in the provided link) for details. For citation purpose, ISBN alone should be sufficient; it is for the physical book and it's as specific as DOI.

Comment: Wait, isn't ISBN for books only? How come an article got one assigned?

Comment: It appears that the reference is a chapter in a conference proceedings. I would think the ISBN refers to the entire proceedings and not the chapter.

Comment: @Penguin_Knight that would make a good answer: please could you post it as one, with a bit of info from that doi.org factsheet thrown in for good measure?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try these sites to search for a CrossRef DOI:

http://search.crossref.org/

or

http://www.crossref.org/guestquery/

Comment: Those did not work.

Comment: Then please make sure whether article has DOI or not?

Comment: It does not have it, so those link do not work.

Comment: If the article does not have a DOI, then those links worked perfectly.